# IF and ELSE Exception in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am trying to catch an exception for two boolean (for if and else separately).

this is what I am working on:

```
from math import *
from decimal import Decimal


def add(self, *args):
    try:
        if all(isinstance(n, int) for n in args):
            print(sum(int(n) for n in args))
        else:
            print(fsum(Decimal(n) for n in args))
    except (NameError, SyntaxError) as e:
        print("Error! {}".format(e))

def main():
    add(a)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Both if and else gives me two exceptions `NameError` and `SyntaxError`, if I give `add(a)` its giving me `NameError` as the exception. But the `except` is not catching the error.

How should I catch the exception for both of them separately?

Comment: `NameError` is not raised in the `if..else`, but in `add(a)`, which is in `main` function. You cannot catch an exception raised in the calling function, in the called function.

Comment: Define `a` as something, then use it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand I think you can try like this.

```
except NameError as e :
      print "Name error occured"
      print("Error! {}".format(e))
except SyntaxError as f:
      print "Syntax error occurred"
      print("Error! {}".format(f))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, person who gave me -1, just to let you know that it was an honest mistake and i am new to python. keeping that aside.

so just got to know that `SyntaxError` are thrown at compile time which cannot be caught at run time that is what -> [[SyntaxError not excepting in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662999/syntaxerror-not-excepting-in-python-3][1]) says

so I figured it and thanks to @thefourtheye

```
from math import *
from decimal import Decimal


    def add(*args):

        if all(isinstance(n, int) for n in args):
            print(sum(int(n) for n in args))
        else:
            print(fsum(Decimal(n) for n in args))


    def main():
        try:
            add(dfvdv)
        except NameError:
            print("Error!")

    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```